# Python: Destination Unreachable (Port unreachable) between two computers

Tags: python, linux, windows, networking

I've recently ran into a problem where my Windows machine where I do my development and my Linux server which processes the data I feed it have become disconnected.

To explain further, a little backstory. Previously the two machines communicated without any problem, then after awhile I wasn't able to connect to the Linux server/vice-versa with Python. Pinging the Windows host I was receiving essentially it didn't exist. I actually went as far as to swap routers to ensure that the router wasn't the problem but the problem persisted. I eventually had to add in firewall rules for ICMP and it worked but that didn't make too much sense as it was fine before, removing that and looking forward I found a solution. Something with a Windows update turned off my network discovery, upon going to File Explorer -> Networking -> Enable network discovery did this finally work again. PING SUCCESSFUL.

Now I'm trying to get Python working again. I've setup simple test scripts on both sides to test the client (Windows) - server (Linux) communication.

**Windows**

```
(base) C:\Users\Kyle>python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> sock.sendto(b'hello', ('192.168.1.127', 50000))
5
>>> sock.sendto(b'hello', ('192.168.1.127', 50000))
5
>>> sock.sendto(b'hello', ('192.168.1.127', 5000))
5
>>>
```

**Linux**

```
(base) kyle@alfred:~$ python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> sock.bind(('localhost', 5000)) # Previous test was 50,000 hence Windows having two different port tests
>>> sock.settimeout(10)
>>> sock.recvfrom(2048)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.timeout: timed out
>>>
```

[image: Wireshark capture]

A few debugging notes

1. Windows machine was setup using DHCP for IP ...128
2. Linux machine was setup using DHCP for IP ...127
3. Linux machine **was** running Ubuntu 18.04, recent wipe to upgrade **20.04**.
4. Windows can ping the Linux server, Linux server can ping the Windows client.
5. UPDATE: My chromeos system with crew was unable to send a message to my Linux server using the same Python "script" I used for Windows. Maybe this is a router issue after all?
6. UPDATE: My chromeos system with crew was unable to receive a message from my Windows client using the same Python "script". The only thing different is that the Windows wireshark hadn't raised Port unreachable.
7. UPDATE: This should be final and probably point to a router issue? But my server to chromeos failed, same ordeal and not Port unreachable.

Feel free to request whatever, critique whatever. I do need this communication happening relatively soon.

Still accepting requests for work arounds on the router, leaving this question open but I'm like 99.9% sure now its definitely a router related issue. I did try bridging earlier but no success, though, it could've been a wrong config but I wasn't able to get internet access through to my server.

Comment: Did you try binding 0.0.0.0 in your linux server like sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5000)) instead of sock.bind(('localhost', 5000)) ?

Comment: I hadn't but good idea though same result.